# How to change jquery Deferred to use Vue nexttick?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, deferred

I need to change this as I have read nextTick is a better option compared to deferred.

This is the original code that works well:

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchOverdraftLogs', 'setOverdraftFilters', 'fetchUserEventsCsvFile']),
},
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getOverdraftLogs'])
  },
...
        loadData: filters => {
          const d = $.Deferred()
          this.fetchOverdraftLogs({ params: this.filtersToSend(filters) })
            .then(res => {
              d.resolve(this.getOverdraftLogs)
              this.setFilterValues()
            })
          return d.promise()
        })
        }
```

However, I am not able to rework this with nextTick:

```
loadData: filters => {
  this.fetchOverdraftLogs({ params: this.filtersToSend(filters) })
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.setFilterValues()
    this.getOverdraftLogs
  })
}
```

I need to make sure for the grid that after the API is called it reads the data from the state.

Could you assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred pattern is generally an antipattern, especially with ES promises. It's not an alternative to `nextTick`. Promises are already asynchronous, a promise that is instantly resolved provides a small delay. `nextTick` provides a delay that is big enough DOM to be updated.

`nextTick` supports promises but here it's not needed.

It should be:

```
    loadData: filters => {
      return this.fetchOverdraftLogs({ params: this.filtersToSend(filters) })
        .then(() => {
          this.setFilterValues()
          return this.getOverdraftLogs;
        })
    }
```

Vuex actions aren't supposed to return data they operate on, so there should be no `res`.